# TypeError at /BookList/frame (Dynamic path not working in Django)

Tags: python, django, django-views

so i tried to make a dynamic path in django but when i pass 'frame' as argument in the view function 'details_meetups' that error show up
function i got this error.
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTjsU.png)

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('BookList', BookList.views.index),
path('BookList/<frame>', BookList.views.Meetup_Details)]


def Meetup_Details(request,frame):
    selected_one = {"name":"jacob",
    "description":"tall"}
    return render('request,BookList/meetup-detail.html',{
         "name" : selected_one["name"],
         "description" : selected_one["description"]
}
)
```

Comment: `return render(request, 'BookList/...', ...)`.

Comment: Update your question with `indentation` properly, what is `)` at last?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using render() correctly:

```
return render(request, 'BookList/meetup-detail.html',{
     "name" : selected_one["name"],
     "description" : selected_one["description"]
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render